# find duplication based on rest rows value in df

Tags: python, pandas

i cant find the solution. i must know, a value got duplicates later than datetime field value
i know my dirty redundant code is soooo slow, just find a solution (for few thousend records time not so important)

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

data='''m_num|m_dt|name
24|12.21 05:30|Duka A. (Rus)
24|12.21 05:30|Vologzhanin V. (Rus)
25|12.21 05:45|Arutiunyan A. (Rus)
25|12.21 05:45|Tsvetkov V. (Rus)
26|12.21 05:45|Shmakov A. (Rus)
26|12.21 05:45|Klimentev V. (Rus)
33|12.21 07:00|Belugin O. (Rus)
33|12.21 07:00|Duka A. (Rus)
34|12.21 07:15|Gerasimov O. (Ukr)
34|12.21 07:15|Shmakov A. (Rus)
35|12.21 07:15|Tolmachev I. (Rus)
35|12.21 07:15|Arutiunyan A. (Rus)
36|12.21 07:30|Duka A. (Rus)
36|12.21 07:30|Bogomolov A. (Rus)
37|12.21 07:45|Arutiunyan A. (Rus)
37|12.21 07:45|Olshakov K. (Rus)'''

df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='|',header=0)
print(df)
print('--------------------')

for idx,a in df.iterrows():
    a_time=pd.to_datetime(a['m_dt'], format = '%m.%d %H:%M')
    df_rest=df[pd.to_datetime(df['m_dt'], format = '%m.%d %H:%M') > a_time]
    print(len(df_rest))
    b=a['name']
    c=df_rest['name'].values.tolist()
    df.loc[lambda df: df['m_num'] == a, 'dupe']=any(b in s for s in list(c))
```

**this works:**

```
pd.to_datetime(df['m_dt'], format = '%m.%d %H:%M')
for idx,a in df.iterrows():
    df_rest=df[df['m_dt'] > a['m_dt']]
    name_ls=df_rest['name'].values.tolist()
    df.loc[idx, 'dupe'] = any(a['name'] in s for s in name_ls)
print(df)
```

Comment: The purpose is not clear to me. Pandas has a built-in function to find duplicate rows https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html, where you can indicate the subset of columns (e.g., [m_num, m_dt] ) for identifying duplicated rows.

Comment: Also using `\t` with code that will be copy pasted is not good as we will all have to infer, delete and replace where we thing the tabs will be.  Much better to use | or \.

Comment: Also why are you doing the conversion to datatime inside the loop the datetime conversion can happen outside the loop once and be used as a datime all the time

Comment: Try this: `df.name.duplicated('last')`.